# JQuery Mobile - Persistent header/navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile

is there a way to keep a persistent header in jQuery mobile?
I'd like to benefit from the changePage functionality and events offered by the framework, but want to keep the navigation the same across pages.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, jQuery Mobile's persistent headers disappears/reappears when you scroll.

But they are experimenting with a scrollview which might provide the functionality you are looking for. You can see the docs for the scrollview [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/).

Other than that, there's always [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)